# Is it possible to use an SVG rect as the border for an HTML element with variable height

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to use SVG to create a dotted border around an HTML block with a fixed width but flexible height. I'm tantalisingly close but can't get the bottom to display.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoLppgty/) (the fiddle has the SVG image included, so it can be inline there URL encoded elements, specifically `#` is `%23`)

The SVG code looks like this:

```
<svg width="300px" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="5" y="5" width="290" height="100%" 
    style="fill: yellow; fill-opacity: 0.5; stroke: #009fe3; stroke-width: 3; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-dasharray: 1 7"/>
</svg>
```

The CSS like this:

```
div.block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("dotted-border.svg");
}
```

I guess what I want is to offset the rectangle from the bottom, but it needs to be a pixel value (`5px`).  It looks like what I want will be trivial with wider SVG 2 adoption (http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Stroke_position) as then the stroke could be positioned inside the shape.

I know I could just add another image and use CSS `:after`, but I'm curious!

Comment: you could use the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute but the dotted lines will look stretched or squeezed according to the content height : http://jsfiddle.net/eoLppgty/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a straightforward CSS border instead?

```css
div.block {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width='300px' height='100%' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect x='5' y='5' width='290' height='100%' style='fill: yellow; fill-opacity: 0.5; stroke: %23009fe3; stroke-width: 3; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-dasharray: 1 7'/></svg>");
}

div.block2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 4px;
    margin:3px;
    width: 294px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    border:3px dotted #009fe3;
}

/* Alternative method using CSS3 border-image: */
div.block3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 4px;
    margin:3px;
    width: 294px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    border:8px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAbklEQVR4nGL4W8zBMJAYmbMCiJ9C8Qosimkijyz5Hw2vQNNME3mYgqdYFDxFMoBm8oPGAQMeBQOeCAdFNhxwB4yWA6PlwGg5MODZcMAdMFoOjJYDo+XAgGfDAXfAaDkwWg6MlgMDggEAAAD//wMAIRKl6nQ6gLIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) round;
    -o-border-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAbklEQVR4nGL4W8zBMJAYmbMCiJ9C8Qosimkijyz5Hw2vQNNME3mYgqdYFDxFMoBm8oPGAQMeBQOeCAdFNhxwB4yWA6PlwGg5MODZcMAdMFoOjJYDo+XAgGfDAXfAaDkwWg6MlgMDggEAAAD//wMAIRKl6nQ6gLIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) round;
    border-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAbklEQVR4nGL4W8zBMJAYmbMCiJ9C8Qosimkijyz5Hw2vQNNME3mYgqdYFDxFMoBm8oPGAQMeBQOeCAdFNhxwB4yWA6PlwGg5MODZcMAdMFoOjJYDo+XAgGfDAXfAaDkwWg6MlgMDggEAAAD//wMAIRKl6nQ6gLIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) round;
    border-image-slice: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quasi officia vero aut. Velit ratione sapiente fugiat rerum eos ipsa praesentium autem similique vitae reprehenderit et tempora optio eveniet facilis. (SVG)</article>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="block2">
    <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quasi officia vero aut. Velit ratione sapiente fugiat rerum eos ipsa praesentium autem similique vitae reprehenderit et tempora optio eveniet facilis. (CSS)</article>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="block3">
    <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quasi officia vero aut. Velit ratione sapiente fugiat rerum eos ipsa praesentium autem similique vitae reprehenderit et tempora optio eveniet facilis. (CSS3)</article>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm wanting to use dots not dashes.  It makes more sense when they are a little larger (rounder).

Comment: @bloke_zero In that case, perhaps you could use a CSS3 border image. I'll edit my answer to add an example.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage after careful this seems like the right answer for right now, pity the corners are borked in Safari, but maybe they'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to calculate the right height in svg. instead of using background image, wrap the svg with absolutely positioned div:

*HTML*

```
<div class="block">
    <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quasi officia vero aut. Velit ratione sapiente fugiat rerum eos ipsa praesentium autem similique vitae reprehenderit et tempora optio eveniet facilis.</article>
    <div class="back-svg">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect width="100%" height="100%" style='fill: yellow; fill-opacity: 0.5; stroke: #009fe3; stroke-width: 5; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-dasharray: 1 7'/></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
}
div.block {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
div.back-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3v4by34/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8ojbf9Lh/2/ I still can't get the bottom line to show.

Comment: @bloke_zero: I have simplified it and added fiddle url

Comment: thanks - this does answer the question, but I think the need for extra mark-up is a problem.

Comment: @bloke_zero ok, then you should make the border using CSS and optionally use background SVG without border

Comment: @bloke_zero you can add the absolute div to all div.block elements on runtime